# How the Stream Server v0.6.3 read the PNG data via AJAX sent from the Dart Client 0.4.3_r20602?

Tags: ajax, stream, httprequest, computer-science, dart

Stream Server v0.6.3
Dart Editor 0.4.3_r20602
Dat SDK 0.4.3.5_r26062

How the Dart Server(Stream) read the PNG data or Sring via AJAX sent from the Dart Client?
Not like PHP, Dart's HttpRequest doesn't have property of request.text.

Answer (score 1):

In general , we can use StringDecoder() to transform the incoming list of int from request to stream, then use the listen event of stream to handle the value.

For a tested example, please refer to my recent post. cheers

[Dart 0.4.3_r20602 Stream Server Example of sending and handling PNG client server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816741/dart-0-4-3-r20602-stream-server-example-of-sending-and-handling-png-client-serve)

or search "Dart 0.4.3_r20602 Stream Server Example of sending and handling PNG client server "